# how to poperly deserialize dates in resteasy 3

Tags: json, parsing, date, resteasy, wildfly

I Use resteasy 3.0.8.Final in wildfly8.1. When I POST some date in my json I get

```
Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '2014-06-20 12:00:00': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2014-06-20 12:00:00': Can not parse date "2014-06-20 12:00:00": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

I had tried also with the standard formats mentioned but I get the same message.

How can I configure resteasy to parse the date from a format I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to include the Jackson annotations package used by rest easy.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Next you will need to annotate your Date fields with the JsonFormat annotation to specify the output format.

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

The other option is to post your date's in one of the supported formats.

Comment: I have figured out it by myself but forgot to post it here...but anyway that is the correct answer, tnx James

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the [JacksonJsonProvider](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/jaxrs/JacksonJsonProvider.html):

```
@Provider
public class JsonProvider extends JacksonJsonProvider {

    public JsonProvider() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = locateMapper(ObjectMapper.class, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
        objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy"));
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    }

}
```

You need to add the `resteasy-jackson-provider` to your classpath:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The `SerializationConfig.Feature` has changed name and package a view times. You can find it in `org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig`.

Comment: I still get the same error. I see the constructor called. But then the settings customised in the object mapper are not used apparently (?)